Nuxt error.vue not rendering on non-existent page trigger, only logs in server console with HTTP ERROR 404
I have error.vue set up alongside app.vue, when I try to trigger the frontend by going to a non-existent page, I get the console.log within the server logs, however it doesn't render the page. All I get is an HTTP ERROR 404 from my browser.
Is there any reason why this could be happening?

The error.vue page should be at the root directory of your Nuxt project and NOT in your /pages directory. This might be what happened to you?

This works either by client-side navigation or manually typing a non-existing path.

That's where it is. The thing is I do get the server logs, but it still doesn't render the page.

@B.Koenig try with a brand new fresh app to be sure that everything works well. Then try to look out for the differences. Works flawlessly on my side. Maybe you have some custom router config? Anyway, try a new app and compare it to yours.
